# Coloured arrows and information outside circles in diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

There's a couple of things I need in my diagrams which I can't seem to figure out how to do. Firstly, I need arrows of two different colours - straight arrows one colour, bent arrows another. And I also need to have information outside of but next to each circle (either`A=1` or `A=0`). Help would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
  %\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black]

  \node[state]       (A)                    {$w_1$};
  \node[state]         (B) [above left of=A] {$w_2$};
  \node[state]         (C) [above right of=A] {$w_3$};


\path (A) edge              node {} (B)
               %edge              node {} (C)
        edge [bend right] node {} (C)
        (B) edge        node {} (A)
            %edge              node {0,1,L} (C)
        %(C) edge              node {0,1,L} (D)
           % edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (E)
        (C) %edge [loop below] node {1,1,R} (C)
            edge              node {} (A);
        %(E) edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add colours as either arguments to the `\path` command and/or to each `edge`.  For example,

```
 \path[red] (A)
 edge (B)
 edge [bend right, blue] (C)
```

will make the default colour `red` but colour the bent curve `blue`.

To put information close to the nodes, add a `label=pos:text` argument to the `\node` statment, e.g.

```
\node[state, label=left:{$A=1$}] (B) {$w_2$};
```

The presence of `=` in your "text" means you have enclose it in `{...}` brackets.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node
  distance=2.8cm, semithick]

  \node[state, label=below:{$A=3$}] (A) {$w_1$};
  \node[state, label=left:{$A=1$}] (B) [above left of=A] {$w_2$};
  \node[state, label=right:{$A=0$}] (C) [above right of=A] {$w_3$};

  \path[red] (A)
  edge node {} (B)
  edge [bend right, blue] node {} (C)
  (B) edge node {} (A)
  (C) edge node {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Should you wish to style the labels you can either set the `every label` style or write something like

```
\node[state, label={[font=\small]left:$A=1$}] (B) {$w_2$};
```